# Extract Base64 That Encoded To Zip PHP

Tags: php, zip, base64, decode, encode

I Have Problem to extract the zip file which created from the `base64` data
Here is my script

```
<?

$basedata =  base64_decode($data['data']);
$f = fopen ("c:/xampp/htdocs/sms/basedata/data.zip","x+");
fwrite($f, $basedata);
fclose($f);

$zip = new ZipArchive();

$res = $zip->open('c:/xampp/htdocs/sms/basedata/data.zip');
if ($res === TRUE) {
  // extract it to the path we determined above
  $zip->extractTo("c:/xampp/htdocs/sms/basedata/extracted");
  $zip->close();
  echo "Success!";
} else {
  echo "Failed!";
}


}

?>
```

First I create the `zip` file from the `fopen` and `fwrite` command
and then Zip file created

and the content of that zip file is file named data , this file actually `xml` file
this `xml` data is comes from decoded base64 data and then encoded to zip

and when i want to exract the zip file with `$res = $zip->open('c:/xampp/htdocs/sms/basedata/data.zip');` command , it can't run because the zip file is not actually zip archive

I Think PHP just can read the zip archive , not the file that encoded to zip

Anyone can help me?

Comment: `ZipArchive` [can zip file](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.addfile.php), you can use it to zip; And [`fopen`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) do not zip file automately, so the file you created is not a valid zip.

Answer (score 0):

Use the function **[addFromString](http://php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.addfromstring.php)**:

```
$basedata =  base64_decode($data['data']);

$zip = new ZipArchive;
$res = $zip->open('c:/xampp/htdocs/sms/basedata/data.zip', ZipArchive::CREATE);
if ($res === TRUE) {
    $zip->addFromString('basedata.txt', $basedata);
    $zip->extractTo("c:/xampp/htdocs/sms/basedata/extracted");
    $zip->close();
    echo 'ok';
} else {
    echo 'failed';
}
```